# Tensorflow take ages for tf.cond and eval() - python code (sorry but i asked on Stackoverflow but none answer me)

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow

I got a problem with TensorFlow and need your help.

My need is calculating `tensordot` between a vector: 1x512 named `face` in my code and a faces data: N x 512 named `input_faces_data`. The code will return the `max_value_index` if the `max_value` >= 0.1.

I printed out time stamp to timing each step of function i use:

```
tf.tensordot()
tf.math.argmax()
tf.cond()
tf.Session()
.eval() -> return last value
```

My questions:

- Why `tf.tensordot()` and `tf.math.argmax()` take just 1ms or 5ms with any length of faces data array (3.000 or 1.000.0000 - my examples) but time cost a lot with `.eval` and `tf.cond()`?
- Why the duration of `tf.cond()` and `.eval()` is more longer with longer face data array?

I'm using TensorFlow 1.13.1 and my GPU is GTX 2080 (11GiB).

My Python code:

```
sess = tf.Session()
with tf.device(Config.GPU.GPU_DEVICE):
    start = time.time()
    dot_array = tf.tensordot(input_faces_data, face, axes=1)
    print("Data length {}".format(len(faces_data)))
    print("Compatition time {}".format(time.time()-start))
    start_max_index = time.time()
    max_index = tf.math.argmax(dot_array)
    print("get max_value_index time {}".format(time.time()-start_max_index))
    start_condition_time = time.time()
    new_max_index = tf.cond(dot_array[max_index] > tf.constant(0.1),
                            lambda: max_index,lambda: tf.constant(-1,dtype=tf.int64))
    print("tf.cond time {}".format(time.time()-start_condition_time))
    temp_max_index = -1
    start_seesion = time.time()
    with sess:
        print("Session time {}".format(time.time() - start_seesion))
        start_eval_time = time.time()
        temp_max_index = new_max_index.eval()
        print("Eval time {}".format(time.time() - start_eval_time))
    print("Total time {}, max_index {}".format(time.time()-start,temp_max_index))
```

And my outputs:

[image: 1.000.000]
[image: 3.000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `tf.tensordot()`, `tf.math.argmax()` doesn't change running regardless of the input size is because they don't make the operations, but rather declare it.

It is similar to passing a partial function using functools.partial, the function is not really executed, it just determines it's inputs (or part of it).

```py
from functools import partial
def tensordot(a,b):
    return partial(lambda a,b: a*b,a,b)
```

While running eval will run the previously mounted model

```py
dot = tensordot(a,b) #dot here is a function
dot() # <- done inside eval
```

Actually, on tensorflow these "partials" are objects and when you eval one of then, the previously declared objects that it depends of will be evaluated

Comment: Thank you for your help! @Pedro Henrique Monforte.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem consider upvoting/accepting it. Also, on Stack Exchange sites it is not proper to right comments such as "thank you" or "that was helpful" since voting accomplishes that and adding it as a comment would simply fill the  comment section with spam.